# Why is Mongoose giving user validation errors for required fields even though I fill them properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, validation, mongoose

I am creating a user registration system using Node.js, express.js and mongoDB in MVC format. When I send reponse through postman, it works perfectly but when I try to send through my frontend, the data is not ebing passed for some reason

this is my userModel:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    mobile:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    is_admin:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    is_verified:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```js
This is my userController: 
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const loadRegister = async(req, res) =>{
    try {
        res.render('registration')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

const insertUser = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            mobile: req.body.mno,
            password: req.body.password,
            is_admin: 0
        });

        const userData = await user.save();

        if(userData){
            res.render('registration',{message:'Account created successfully!'})
        }
        else{
            res.render('registration',{message:'Cannot Create Account!'})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    loadRegister,
    insertUser,
}
```

This is my userRoute:

```js
const express = require("express");
const user_route = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

user_route.set('view engine', 'ejs');
user_route.set('views', './views/users');

// user_route.use(bodyParser.json());
// user_route.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
user_route.use(express.json());
user_route.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

user_route.get('/register', userController.loadRegister);
user_route.post('/register', userController.insertUser);

module.exports = user_route;
```

and finally this is my ejs view file saved as /views/users/registration.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Heal PTSD</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>User Registration Form</h1>

    <form action="/register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="text" name="mno" placeholder="Enter Mobile" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Register">
        <br> <br>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using both bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}) and express.json(), express.urlencoded({extended:true}), along with that I have checked all the names of the tags, they match perfectly with that in userController. Nothing is working! I would be really grateful if someone can help me with it.

Comment: So long as you are using Express >= v4.16.0 then `express.json()` *is* `bodyParser.json()` so you can get rid of the `require('body-parser');` same goes for the `urlencoded` function. In your `insertUser` function do a `console.log(req.body)` and then send the HTML form (don't use postman). What is the output?

Comment: Also if you are not uploading a file such as an image etc then change your form to `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Not having an `enctype` will also default to that but better to be explicit. That is what is likely causing your issue.